# Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Must be authenticated! Hardhat Node.js Alchemy

Tags: node.js, json-rpc, hardhat, alchemy

I set up Hardhat in VScode with the required dependencies, running an Alchemy node with Metamask. I've tried most of the troubleshoots I have found online and have read most of the documentation but I'm still lost.. Whatever information you need I can provide. Anything helps. Thank you so much. I'm pretty new to this so please work with me.

**Here is the error I receive:**

```html
npx hardhat node
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Must be authenticated!
```

**Hardhat.config.ts**

```
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";
import "@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades";

import "hardhat-deploy";

import { resolve } from "path";

import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import { NetworkUserConfig } from "hardhat/types";

dotenvConfig({ path: resolve(__dirname, "./.env") });

const chainIds = {
    goerli: 5,
    hardhat: 1337,
    kovan: 42,
    mainnet: 1,
    rinkeby: 4,
    ropsten: 3,
};

// Ensure that we have all the environment variables we need.
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
// Make sure node is setup on Alchemy website
const alchemyApiKey = process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY;

function getChainConfig(network: keyof typeof chainIds): NetworkUserConfig {
    const url = `https://eth-${network}.alchemyapi.io/v2/${alchemyApiKey}`;
    return {
        accounts: [`${privateKey}`],
        chainId: chainIds[network],
        url,
    };
}

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    gasReporter: {
        currency: "USD",
        enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS ? true : false,
        excludeContracts: [],
        src: "./contracts",
    },
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            forking: {
                url: `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${alchemyApiKey}`,
            },
            chainId: chainIds.hardhat,
        },
        // Uncomment for testing. Commented due to CI issues
        // mainnet: getChainConfig("mainnet"),
        // rinkeby: getChainConfig("rinkeby"),
        // ropsten: getChainConfig("ropsten"),
    },
    paths: {
        artifacts: "./artifacts",
        cache: "./cache",
        sources: "./contracts",
        tests: "./test",
        deploy: "./scripts/deploy",
        deployments: "./deployments",
    },
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.8.10",
                settings: {
                    metadata: {
                        bytecodeHash: "none",
                    },
                    optimizer: {
                        enabled: true,
                        runs: 800,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                version: "0.8.10",
                settings: {
                    metadata: {
                        bytecodeHash: "none",
                    },
                    optimizer: {
                        enabled: true,
                        runs: 800,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                version: "0.7.5",
                settings: {
                    metadata: {
                        bytecodeHash: "none",
                    },
                    optimizer: {
                        enabled: true,
                        runs: 800,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                version: "0.5.16",
            },
            {
                version: "0.8.10",
                settings: {
                    metadata: {
                        bytecodeHash: "none",
                    },
                    optimizer: {
                        enabled: true,
                        runs: 800,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
        settings: {
            outputSelection: {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["storageLayout"],
                },
            },
        },
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0,
        },
        daoMultisig: {
            // mainnet
            1: "HIDDEN",
        },
    },
    typechain: {
        outDir: "types",
        target: "ethers-v5",
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
    mocha: {
        timeout: 1000000,
    },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is usually shown when the Alchemy URL is incorrect. You can try verifying the key once if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made sure the Alchemy URL is correct. After adding the API key to your project, you can also grab the Alchemy URL(found in the alchemy dashboard)  and add it to your project as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494469)